# Where does the parameters comes from in anonymous functions of jQuery events?

Tags: jquery

When I started learning jQuery I didn´t know anything about that it's a Framework of JavaScript and, in general, I didn't know anything about JavaScript. Now I'm trying to learn how works jQuery in respect to JavaScript, but I can't understand part of jQuery syntax.

```
$('#element').keypress(function(z) {

})
```

On the previous jQuery event there is a anonymous function —I think that it's a anonymous function. Correct me if I'm wrong please. In this function there's a parameter 'z' that we can use inside this event to know which key was pressed with .which property. So my questions are:

What is this parameter of the function? Why this parameter has relation with the .keypress event?

Comment: You probably want to read: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/keypress/ you will see that the signature of the `keypress` method that you are using is:

```
.keypress( handler(eventObject) )
```

It clarifies below that the handler is a function. The syntax tells you that the function takes a single parameter which is an `eventObject`. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ gives more details of this object.

Answer (score 1):

The only argument that can be handled by the anonymous function is the event passed in by the DOM. What you call the parameter is arbitrary, `e` and `evt` are two commonly accepted values to be used.

Inside your anonymous function, you can utilize `z` in your case to access any of the available properties and methods of the `keypress` object.

Some examples include but aren't limited to:

```
$('#element').keypress(function(z){
  var key = z.which; //the specific key that was pressed
  var target = z.target; //what HTML element is the target of the event?
  var posx = z.pageX; //the mouse X position when the key was pressed
  var posy = z.pageY; //the mouse Y position when the key was pressed
}
```

Comment: actually, jQuery passes in a normalised event object, not the original one passed in by the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the functions you pass in as event handlers are invoked internally by jQuery, and thus the library (or the people who wrote it) got to choose how they wanted to invoke the functions.

By specifying a contract (i.e., announcing that event handlers would get a single parameter which represented the "event object") and then following that contract in their own library, this allows developers like you to take advantage of the contract in your callbacks by expecting an event object to be passed in as the first parameter of your callback. In the case of `.keypress()`, jQuery calls the handler you specify with its event object as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

```
.keypress( handler(eventObject) )
```

That means that `keypress()` accepts an handler [i.e. a `function`] that will have an [`eventObject`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) passed as a parameter.

jQuery will take care of detecting when the `keypress` event is triggered, then will execute your handler [either anonymous or properly defined], e.g.:

```
var myHandler = function(event){...}

$(document).keypress(myHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is normally passed as `e` or `event` for readability. It is the jQuery normalized [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), which is guaranteed to be passed to any handler (read the docs linked).

So, for example, to do something when the user hits "Enter":

```
$('#element').keypress(function (z) {

    // e.which is a normalized e.keyCode / e.charCode
    // see http://api.jquery.com/event.which/ 
    if (z.which === 13) {
        console.log("zomg why is the event passed as z?");
    }
});
```